# Mounting SMB network share from Mavericks recovery mode

Tags: backup, disk-utility, smb, recovery-hd

I would like to be able back up my macbook on a weekly basis doing the following:

- boot into recovery mode
- mount a windows SMB network share
- use disk utility to save a disk image to the network share
- possibly automate this process

This seems like it should be possible however when I try and mount the SMB share I get this error message:

```
-bash-3.2# mount_smbfs
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SMBClient.framework/Versions/A/SMBClient
   Referenced from: /sbin/mount_smbfs
   Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have also attempted to copy the framework folder from the main system volume. However the recovery partition is read-only.

Am I incorrectly trying to mount the SMB share or do I have to make a custom recovery image thats supports SMB?

Answer (score 2):

This is, because the binary for the framework that’s required is not part of the Recovery System.

I have been trying various things for over an hour now and the only thing that works appears to be AFP:

```
mkdir /Volumes/VOLUMENAME
mount_afp afp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@000.00.000.00/VOLUMENAME /Volumes/VOLUMENAME
```

One important thing that kept this from working for me was that I had used `/Volumes/VOLUMENAME` instead of the correct `/VOLUMENAME` in the afp URL.

Comment: still true for Big Sur