# Is it Possible to Mount SMB share in Internet Recovery?

Tags: time-machine, mount, smb, sparsebundle, internet-recovery

I'm currently setting up a Time Machine backup on a Windows Server. The simple method is to create a sparsebundle image on the Windows Share and mount that in macOS which works fine. In the past though mostly due to meddling I have had to use Internet Recovery to restore a Time Machine backup, this has worked for USB drives but obviously this is different.

Can I mount an smb share in Internet Recovery using Terminal, then mount the sparsebundle image to restore the Time Machine backup? or as I have struggled to find a concrete answer on, is only AFP supported in Internet Recovery?

Comment: Wondering the same thing. In particular, I thought even apple was abandoning AFP.

Comment: This question from 2014 still seems to hold: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122389/mounting-smb-network-share-from-mavericks-recovery-mode?rq=1   When I try and mount the SMB volume, I get an error message about the shared objects not being loaded. So SMB must not be supported in recovery mode.

Comment: This document from apple explicitly states TM over network should be SMB: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/types-of-disks-you-can-use-with-time-machine-mh15139/mac

Comment: I am getting the impression that you can only restore from a network TM backup with Migration assistant